Can we always find a line segment that is perpendicular to two skew lines in space?
I read somewhere that the distance between two skew lines in 3D is the length of the line perpendicular to both of the given lines. The question is, does such a line always exist? And if there is, is it unique? How can I make sure that the length of that line segment is the shortest distance between two skew lines?

Vector cross product may help

@YvesDaoust Not exactly the same question, but the answers given there do address (in my opinion) all the issues raised by the OP.

Here's a way to see that there is one by reducing it to an easy to visualize case, which is often a useful trick. Apply rigid transformations (rotations, translations) so that one of the lines is on the $x$ axis. Then rotate about the $x$ axis until the other line lies in some plane parallel to the $xy$ plane. Then the unique line perpendicular to both is the line parallel to the $z$ axis that intersects both of them (to see one exists, project down onto the $xy$ plane, since the lines are skew, the projections can't be parallel).
You can now rephrase the argument without having to apply the transformations by replacing the $x$ axis with the first line and the $xy$ plane with the unique plane containing the first line and not intersecting the second (note a plane and a line will generically intersect at a point, they only don't if they're parallel i.e. intersect "at infinity").
